# Multi-column list of lists

Tags: javascript, css, django, jstree

I'm using jstree with django on the server-side. The tree structure is obviously vertically(one column list), what I'd like to do is to split the tree into 3+ columns.

I followed [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/) advice but I couldn't make it work when I tried to adapt the advice for my problem. I have lists of lists and each list can be expanded or not, which makes it more difficult.

I thougth about splitting the tree into three or more different trees, it's not a nice solution but I think it might work.

This is what I generate with Django and what is used by jstree to render the tree.

```
<div id="tree" class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Philosophers</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="96">Socrates</a></li>
                <li><a id="97">Epictetus</a></li>
                <li><a id="98">Seneca</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
    </ul>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: So you want jsTree where the nodes will be in 3 columns? How would it look like when you open nodes in two or 3 columns?